# Differents SELECTs clauses change the number of rows (with same WHERE condition)

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this **issue** (maybe not an error).

On an Oracle View, **the columns in SELECT change the number of rows obtained from DB.**

It's an error with the definition of the VIEW?

I think this incident only could be possible with VIEWS but never in TABLES, or not?

```sql
--16 ROWS
SELECT *
FROM MY_ORACLE_VIEW
WHERE CONDITION_1 = 'A' AND CONDITION_2 = 'B';

--112 ROWS
SELECT COLUMN_X, COLUMN_Y
FROM MY_ORACLE_VIEW
WHERE CONDITION_1 = 'A' AND CONDITION_2 = 'B';
```

Note: The real view are very complex

**Oracle Version** from (SELECT * FROM V$VERSION):

- Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
- PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
- CORE 11.2.0.4.0  Production
- TNS for HPUX: Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
- NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production

Comment: No, that shouldn't even happen in views. That's pretty weird. There must be more to it.

Comment: Agreed, this should never happen. Did you compare the plans for both queries?

Comment: @dnoeth The plans are different. (Im not the owner of the view)

Comment: The complexity of the view might be an issue. Also, some optimizer statements in your view might lead Oracle to trip over the query. I have seen this issues with complex views, group by's and unions combined.

Comment: Can you specify the query, version of database, platform, patches, etc.?

Comment: No matter why, this is a wrong result and should be treated as such. Open an incident with your Oracle support.

Comment: @dnoeth: Not entire true it think. I think that if the optimizer hints you pass in are incorrect, it is possible you get invalid results. Then they will say it is 'by design'.

Comment: @PatrickHofman thanks for reply, I edited the post (Oracle Version added & HPUX).

Comment: Can you post the view too?

Comment: The view might have columns defined in a way that breaks for some rows. For example, `to_number(x) AS COLUMN_Z` where `x` is a numerical string for some rows, but not numerical for others. In that case, `select *` delivers a few rows before running into the problem, while `select COLUMN_X,COLUMN_Y` avoids it and delivers more rows.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if the `VIEW` target a growing table. 
Or maybe if the `VIEW` is using a TIME variable in the where clause.

You also can try create your own simple view to see if that is a recurrent issue.

Anyway unless you provide the view code we can only speculate about it.